# How to create a new layout to divide into 4 columns in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am a newbie to magento .I have created a custom layout page & it appears in admin dropdown as well. But I don't know what code to put to divide it into 4 columns ?Can anyone explain me how html is generated ?

```
<container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
```

What is header.container ?Where is it located

This is my default.xml.

```
<page layout="4columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/custom-logo.jpg</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">100</argument> 
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="fouth.column">
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="home-page-block">
<arguments>
   <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">home-page-block</argument>
<arguments>
</block>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: You can have ideas from here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html. Also check [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102349/magento-2-create-new-page-header-section) answer if it helps you anyway.

Comment: I already checked these links & created a new layout.But my question is what  to add in this file to divide int o4 columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like all you've done is declare a new page layout in layouts.xml without actually adding a new layout? If so then you will need to add an XML file for the page layout which is where you set up your 4 columns.

There are a few ways you can do this and it depends on your requirements and the way you work which way is best for you, in my example I'll do it the same way the other columns have been created in Magento 2.

### Page Layout XML

Create `app/design/frontend/VENDOR-NAME/THEME-NAME/Magento_Theme/page_layout/4columns.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="3columns"/>

    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="fourth.column" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="fourth-column" after="-">

        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

In here we 'extend' the 3columns layout (rather than reinvent the wheel), and add our container (column) into the layout. Then we add our new column to (the already set up) columns container.

### Adding content to the new column

You can now add any content you wish into this column as you normally would in a layout file (not page_layout)!. For example in `app/design/frontend/VENDOR-NAME/THEME-NAME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`:

```
<referenceContainer name="fourth.column">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="example.content" template="Magento_Cms::homepage/homepage-carousel.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

### Styling

If you set a page to use the 4 columns layout you should now see the content for your 4th column, although it won't yet be floating alongside the other columns. To achieve this try something along the lines of:

```
.page-layout-4columns .fourth-column,
.page-layout-4columns .sidebar,
.page-layout-4columns .main {
     float: left;
     width: 33.333%;
}
```

I haven't checked whether that CSS is correct or not so you'll likely need to change it to suit your needs. I know that 33.333% isn't 4 quarters but if I remember rightly two columns are in .main, or at least on the product page (the gallery and the product info are classed as 2 columns but both are in main).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I followed everything you mentioned but still it does not change my Home page layout.

Comment: Can you please just check my default.xml file? Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: @user2431224 - Yeah you haven't closed the last arguments tag, it needs to be </arguments> instead of <arguments>.  Also I made a typo in my answer that I've fixed, I spelt it fouth instead of fourth.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me in Magento 2.2, I don't see the fourth column. Is there maybe some missing details in your explanation ?

Comment: Have you cleared the Magento cache?

Comment: @BenCrook, what types of changes  in default.xml file .In my case not show this option after followed above steps.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file for layout,

`<page layout="4columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">`

In the page tag, you can set layout attribute with your desired column layout.

To define the 4 column page layout:

- Create a layouts.xml file in view/frontend directory.

  > `<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
  >   <layout id="4columns">
  >       <label translate="true">4 columns</label>
  >   </layout>
  >   </page_layouts>`
- Create 4columns.xml file in view/frontend/page_layout directory.
  Define your layout here in between layout tag like this...

  > `<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
  >   __your element placement will go here.__
  >   </layout>`

Comment: I wrote a code like this : but no change :-(

Comment: where have you created the layout file for 4 columns and by which name ?

Comment: I have created my own theme & I have palced both the xml files as you have mentioned . this is my code for 4columns.xml            
         <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
  <update handle="3columns"/>
 </layout>

Comment: this should work after clearing cache.

Comment: I have cleared cache.But still the same.

Comment: use 4columns instead of 4column in your layout xml file which I written earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41493/discussion-between-user2431224-and-aman-srivastava).

Comment: I did the same but no luck.